# How do I retrieve json object from PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.4, how do I retrieve json object like this:

```
parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
parentToChildReference: [
    {childTableFirstProp: 'another string'},
    {childTableFirstProp: 'yet another string'}
}]
```

instead of this:

```
[{
    parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
    childTableFirstProp: 'another string',
},{
    parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
    childTableFirstProp: 'yet another string'
}]
```

Do I always have to make 2 select queries, and insert one to another by usage of aliases?

**Update 1**

I've tried to use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
"public"."ParentTable".*,
"public"."ChildTable".*
FROM
"public"."ParentTable"
RIGHT JOIN "public"."ChildTable"
ON "public"."ParentTable"."childReference"
```

I will try to explain, what does `ParentTable` and `ChildTable` contain:

```
ParentTable = {
    id: 111
    parentTableFirstProp: 'string',
    parentToChildReference: [222, 333]
}

ChildTable = [{
    id: 222,
    childTableFirstProp: 'another string'
},{
    id: 333,
    childTableFirstProp: 'yet another string'
}]
```

Comment: Please provide: Postgres version, table definition, a valid json literal and the query you tried, even if it's not working.

Comment: I've added this information to the question, also, i've found out an error in my initial question. Could you check it again, please?

Comment: Please provide valid JSON literals. (with double quotes) so we can work with them. And table definitions showing data types and constraints - what you get in psql with `\d tbl` or `CREATE TABLE` scripts.